# Burninate the Martin Gardner tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I recently discovered that we have a [martin-gardner](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martin-gardner) tag. Martin Gardner was a man who wrote about puzzles (of many different kinds), not a type of puzzle. **What use is this tag?** Does it tell people anything about the puzzle? He wrote about [checkerboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkerboard), [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars), [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), [logic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-puzzle), [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), and many other types of puzzle, so certainly it doesn't narrow down the field very much! Who's going to decide "I want to filter puzzles that are of a type written about by Martin Gardner"? If they know anything about Martin Gardner, they'll probably already know about the kinds of puzzle he wrote about, so they can filter by [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars) or whatever.

**EDIT**: since the Martin Gardner tag tells us nothing about what *kind* of puzzle is concerned, it wouldn't work as the *only* tag on a question. That makes it a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and therefore (correct me if I'm wrong) ripe for burnination.

Comment: Is it really true that nobody would search for a Martin Gardner puzzle?

Comment: @Emrakul But what *is* a "Martin Gardner puzzle"? He wrote about almost every kind of puzzle there is! That's my point really. If there is a particular kind of puzzle that can be called a "Martin Gardner puzzle", then of course it makes sense (and we should edit the tag wiki).

Comment: He wrote quite a number of puzzles, and used many as examples. Perhaps it'd be a good idea to limit the tag to "puzzles written by Martin Gardner," because it's still a useful categorization.

Comment: @Emrakul That sounds fair enough. Could you turn that into an answer? [This](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/10273/revisions) is the issue that motivated this meta post btw.

Comment: Lol, that's an interesting change log xD sorry but it really cracked me up, that martin guy really is stubborn

Comment: "Probably" in that blog post is not "definitely"; it is a heuristic that sometimes (rather frequently, on Puzzling) fails. The real criterion is listed clearly as "does not describe the content of the question."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

At some point the [martin-gardner](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martin-gardner) tag has indeed been abolished. Move along, nothing to see here.

(I'm just posting this so that the question doesn't show up as unanswered any more.)

Comment: ..and rightfully so. Nice cleanup.